# Basic logic/flow of card effects in a trading card game

Tags: java

I've done a simple card game before, I have ideas for the overall flow of the program. The main thing that concerns me is card triggers.

Let's say we have a card called "Guy" with the effect of "Whenever you play another card, gain 2 life". How would I go about incorporating this into my code? Every time I play a card, do I have to check if Guy is on the field, and if he is it will run the code to gain 2 life? This seems like it will clutter the main part of my code really fast when I get more cards in the game due to all the potential triggers. I want to figure out the most optimal way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to keep the code from getting cluttered in this situation is to define which kinds of "events" might happen in your game that your cards might need to react to. For each such event, define a method in the base class of your cards (I'm assuming you know about inheritance and abstract methods and classes; otherwise, you'll need to read up on that first), and implement that method appropriately in each subclass.

```
public abstract class Card {
    protected Player owner; // Assume there's a constructor that sets this
    public abstract void anotherCardWasPlayed(Card theOtherCard);
}

public class GuyCard extends Card {
    public void anotherCardWasPlayed(Card theOtherCard) {
        owner.gainLife(2);
    }
}
```

Whenever a particular event occurs in your game, loop through all your cards and call the corresponding method.

If most of the card classes don't need to do anything for a particular event, you might want to make the method non-`abstract` so that you don't have to implement it in the card classes that aren't interested in it.

At the cost of some extra code for controlling the flow of events, this keeps the code for each card's special rules inside that card's class. This approach is essentially the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), which is very widespread in the Java framework.

If you have special rules for pairs of cards that interact, check out the [Double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) pattern.

Comment: Awesome, this seems exactly what I'm looking for. So I just want to be sure I understand, whenever I play a card for example, I will loop through each card on the field, and call the anotherCardWasPlayed function for each card on the field. So how does this work if the card doesn't have an anotherCardWasPlayed function (If I have a card that doesn't do something when you play a card). Do I just define the function but leave it blank? Will that slow down the program, running blank functions?

Comment: That's correct. Assuming that all card classes extend `Card`, they _must_ have `anotherCardPlayed()`, because that method was declared as abstract in `Card`, so all non-abstract subclasses have to implement it. Alternatively, if you make it non-abstract with an empty body in `Card`, the subclasses who don't override it will inherit the empty method. Calling an empty method should take some tens or hundreds of nanoseconds, so I wouldn't worry about that unless you have millions of cards :-)

Comment: This is an example of the convenience you get by using polymorphism and overriding correctly: you can have a list of `Card` instances, and without knowing exactly what kind each card is, you can simply call `anotherCardPlayed()` on each of them and be confident that the right action will take place.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Aasmund Eldhuset, the Observer pattern is an excellent way to go. Another way of approaching this is to have cards register themselves for notification. A good example of this approach is Swing's Observer and Observable.

They are a bit old, and aren't really typesafe, but we can do better without too much effort.

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/** Like Observable, but type-safe */
public class Event<T> {

    /** Like Observer, but type-safe */
    public interface EventWatcher<T>{
      void onEvent(Event<T> event, T arg);
    }

    private final Set<EventWatcher<T>> Watchers = new HashSet<>(10);

    /** Adds a watcher that will be receive events. */
    public void addWatcher (EventWatcher<T> watcher) {
        if (null != watcher) {
            synchronized(Watchers) {
                Watchers.add(watcher);
            }
        }
    }

    /** Removes a watcher, so that it no longer receives events. */
    public void removeWatcher (EventWatcher<T> watcher) {
        if (null != watcher) {
            synchronized(Watchers) {
                Watchers.remove(watcher);
            }
        }
    }

    /** Removes all watchers attached to this instance. */
    public void clearWatchers () {
        synchronized(Watchers) {
            Watchers.clear();
        }
    }

    /** Notifies all of the watchers for this object, passing them 'arg'. */
    public void fire(T arg) {
        if (null == arg) {
            return;
        }

        // Freeze the list of watchers to be notified
        ImmutableList<EventWatcher<T>> copy_of_watchers;
        synchronized(Watchers) {
            copy_of_watchers = ImmutableList.copyOf(Watchers);
        }

        // Release the monitor before heading off to execute arbitrary code.
        for(EventWatcher<T> watcher : copy_of_watchers) {
            watcher.onEvent(this, arg);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this is really simple with the Java 1.8 lambdas, and not burdensome without them. In your case, it would look something like this:

```
public interface Card {
  void drawnFrom(Deck source);
}

public class AwesomeCard implements Card {
  public void drawnFrom(Deck source) {
      source.CardDrawnEvent.addWatcher((Event<Card> event, Card arg) -> {
          // Give the owner Life
      });
  }
}

public class Deck {
  public Event<Card> CardDrawnEvent = new Event<>();

  public Card draw() {
     Card drawn_card = new AwesomeCard(); 
     drawn_card.drawnFrom(this);
     CardDrawnEvent.fire(drawn_card);
     return drawn_card;
  }
}
```